# Eclipse won't build project after adding .h and .cpp files

Tags: c++, class, makefile, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I created a simple C++ project and made the makefile myself.

The makefile looks like this:

```
all: project1.exe

clean:
    rm main.o project1.exe

project1.exe: main.o
    g++ -g -o project1 main.o 

main.o:
    g++ -c -g main.cpp
```

Originally I just had a main.cpp file. Everything worked until I created a new class (Token.h) and added it to my project. I put a new include statement at the tope of my main file, but when I try to build the project I get this message in the console:

```
make all 
g++ -c -g main.cpp
g++ -g -o project1 main.o 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Token::print()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Token::Token()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [project1.exe] Error 1
```

Anybody know what I have to do in order for my project to build correctly now that I've added a class to it? Do I need to make a change to the makefile? If so, what?

Comment: It will be difficult to help unless you show the source code. But, from reading the error message, do you have an implementation to `Token::print()` and `Token::Token()` anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule to your makefile:

```
token.o : token.cpp token.hpp
    g++ -g -c token.cpp
```

Modify some rules in your makefile:

```
main.o: main.cpp token.hpp
  g++ -g -c main.cpp

project.exe : main.o token.o
  g++ -o project.exe main.o token.o
```

In the above fragment, the `token.hpp` class was added as a dependency to `main.o`. The `token.o` file was added as a dependency to `project.exe` and as a parameter to the linking phase.